# How to design nested classes in a .NET Core API to get to a particular schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am messing around with Entity Framework for the first time in a .NET Core API (using the latest release of .NET Core).

At the moment I have 2 classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinedCompany { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `DBContext` class with

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
```

and I can retrieve this with the following:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync () {
            return await _context.Employees
            .Include(p => p.Skills)
            .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Now, I am using the Entity Framework migrations to create the tables. Using the existing classes I get the following tables two tables:

(1) "Employees" with the columns: Id, FirstName, LastName, Gender, JoinedCompany

(2) "Skills" with the columns: Id, SkillName, EmployeeId

I populated these tables with some data and get back the following when I hit one of the endpoints of the API in postman:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Jess",
        "lastName": "Turner",
        "gender": "F",
        "joinedCompany": "2018-10-04T00:00:00",
        "skills": [
            {
                "skillName": "T-SQL",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Angular",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Vue",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Redux",
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Olivia",
        "lastName": "Lu",
        "gender": "F",
        "joinedCompany": "2015-03-31T00:00:00",
        "skills": [
            {
                "skillName": "Hadoop",
                "id": 5
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Azure Databricks",
                "id": 6
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Spark",
                "id": 7
            },
            {
                "skillName": "Python",
                "id": 8
            },
            {
                "skillName": "T-SQL",
                "id": 9
            }
        ],
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jonah",
        "lastName": "Smythe",
        "gender": "M",
        "joinedCompany": "2020-08-11T00:00:00",
        "skills": [],
        "id": 3
     }
]
```

Now, what I am trying to figure out is how I can design the classes so that when I run create the database using entity framework so that I end up with three tables:

(1) "Employees" with the columns: Id, FirstName, LastName, Gender, JoinedCompany

(1) "EmployeeSkills" with the columns: Id, EmployeeId, SkillId

(2) "Skills" with the columns: Id, SkillName

The reason is that I don't want to store the "SkillName" string over and over for each time it appears for the employee. I just want to use the Id.
This would also change the `GetEmployeesAsync` method I applied above also.
Thank-you.

Comment: I'd try putting an ICollection<Employee> in your Skill class to make it many-to-many.

Comment: See [Relationships - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime JoinedCompany { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill> Skills { get; set; } = new HashSet<EmployeeSkill>();
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SkillName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill> Emploees { get; set; } = new HashSet<EmployeeSkill>();
}

public class EmployeeSkill
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EmployeeSkill> EmployeesSkills { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you. Just to follow up, what should my GetEmployeesAsync method look like now? I tried ```return await _context.Employees.Include(p => p.EmployeesSkills).Include(p => p.Skill).ToListAsync();``` but I just get the following error: ```Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid```

Comment: it depends on whath you need as result at end : var employeesNamesWithSkills = dbContext.Employees
                .Select(x => new 
                { 
                    x.FirstName,
                    x.LastName,
                    Skills = x.Skills
                        .Select(x => x.Skill.SkillName)
                        .ToList()
                })
                .ToList();

Comment: or var skillsNamesWithEmployees = dbContext.Skills
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.SkillName,
                    Employees = x.Emploees
                        .Select(x => new 
                        { 
                            x.Employee.FirstName,
                            x.Employee.LastName
                        })
                        .ToList()
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.SkillName)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.SelectMany(x => x.Employees).ToList());

Comment: I think by default is lazy loading on, that means all related data will be included automatically when you materialize the result, your example not working becouse you can include only entities that are defined as properties in the parent one and are not a collection - Like this dbContext.Employees.Include(p => p.Skills).ToListAsync().Result